# Database design to minimize requests to specific table data

Tags: java, database, spring, postgresql, database-design

I am working on a Spring-MVC application for which we are planning to create API's which can be consumed by external users into their own platform. To do so, the user must create an 'app' on our platform and then the accesstoken can be retrieved which can be used to access data by user, and make modifications to it.

Now, to do so, what I am doing is, I have created a table called as 'appdetails'. The user has to authorize the app, by passing in client-id, secret and I am returning an access-token, which can be used to directly work on data-set of the user who owns the app.

But doing a check everytime if the object being requested, belongs to the owner of app is proving more database calls for each request. How can I effectively minimize these calls. Here is how the database looks like. Please note, I am only putting relevant fields and I am using PostgreSQL. Explanation below image.

[image]

So, now when an user wants to access/POST a canvas object. I am receiving the canvas object and the access-token. But now I have to verify, if the groupid to which it has to be associated is the same as what the app-owner is admin for. More calls are required in Section, note. Here is the SQL code if anyone wants.

```
CREATE TABLE appDetails (
                appid NUMERIC NOT NULL,
                clientsecret VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                clientid VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                accesstoken VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT appid PRIMARY KEY (appid)
);


CREATE TABLE person (
                id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                email VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                appid NUMERIC NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE groupaccount (
                groupid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                groupname VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT groupid PRIMARY KEY (groupid)
);


CREATE TABLE groupmembers (
                memberid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                groupid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT memberid PRIMARY KEY (memberid, groupid)
);


CREATE TABLE canvas (
                canvasid VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                groupid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                memberid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT canvasid PRIMARY KEY (canvasid)
);


CREATE TABLE section (
                sectionid VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                canvasid VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT sectionid PRIMARY KEY (sectionid)
);


CREATE TABLE note (
                noteid VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                sectionid VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT noteid PRIMARY KEY (noteid)
);


ALTER TABLE person ADD CONSTRAINT appDetails_person_fk
FOREIGN KEY (appid)
REFERENCES appDetails (appid)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE groupaccount ADD CONSTRAINT person_groupaccount_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id)
REFERENCES person (id)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE groupmembers ADD CONSTRAINT groupaccount_groupmembers_fk
FOREIGN KEY (groupid)
REFERENCES groupaccount (groupid)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE canvas ADD CONSTRAINT groupaccount_canvas_fk
FOREIGN KEY (groupid)
REFERENCES groupaccount (groupid)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE canvas ADD CONSTRAINT groupmembers_canvas_fk
FOREIGN KEY (memberid, groupid)
REFERENCES groupmembers (memberid, groupid)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE section ADD CONSTRAINT canvas_section_fk
FOREIGN KEY (canvasid)
REFERENCES canvas (canvasid)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE note ADD CONSTRAINT section_note_fk
FOREIGN KEY (sectionid)
REFERENCES section (sectionid)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;
```

Also, are there any technologies I can use to maintain Rate of consumption of API. The simplest I could think of was adding a counter in appdetails. I hope the question is clear, if not, kindly let me know. I will explain further.

Comment: I think your problem is not the DB design, I think it is good. I suggest you to cache those information. A very naïve approach could be a Map, a more reliable one could be something like REDIS. You could use [Spring Data REDIS](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/)

Comment: @FrancescoPitzalis : I was actually checking out Memcached, but this looks more promising. Thanks. Any implementation code which can be useful for my situation, if you have, can you put it in answer, so I can accept. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: The only ambiguous thing is: is the user or the app your client? I mean, do you need to authorize the user or the app to access your data? Or maybe the user AND the app?

Comment: @FrancescoPitzalis The first authorization is completed via passing clientid, clientsecret. Then I am returning an accesstoken, which is a String. Now in all requests, the accesstoken must be included. Currently, from the DB I am getting the AppDetails object, and checking the owner of it. This way, I can only return the Groups for which the person is admin for. I hope I was good in explaining.